# How to create a CHECK constraint from Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, check-constraints

I want to add a check constraint for example

```
ALTER TABLE fruit
ADD CONSTRAINT check_colour CHECK(color IN ('black','white', 'green'))
```

I can do it in the command line, however, I can't find the option to add a check constraint in Mysql Workbench. I can only find triggers, but not check constraints.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL allows the syntax for `check constraint`, but doesn't do anything about it.  Hence, no checks.

The standard answer is to use a trigger to check the values.  In your case, though, I think you should have a `Colors` table and a foreign key constraint:

```
create table Colours (
    ColourId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    Colour varchar(255)
);

ALTER TABLE fruits
    ADD COLUMN ColourId FOREIGN KEY (ColourID) REFERENCES Colours(ColourId);
```

This will ensure that only valid colors are allowed.  If you do this when the table is created, you can add `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Why a trigger? Can't you just use an enum in this case?

Comment: A trigger because the OP mentioned a check constraint and that is the only way to implement that.  An alternative implementation would be using an enum.